# What is the meaning of "When you examine my grandpa, be careful not to pull his finger."?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the following cartoon?

[image: little girl says the following to a doctor about her grandpa]

> When you examine my grandpa, be careful not to pull his finger.

Is the old man a pedophile? If YES, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cartoon is not suggesting the old man is a paedophile. "Pull my finger" has a connotation of "make me fart". I don't know how old the joke is, but I remember hearing it on the radio in the 1960's.

Comment: Yes.  That joke is very, very old.  The set up is that an older person, like "grandpa", is playing with a grandchild or any small -- and therefore naive -- child.  "grandpa" holds out his hand and tells the child "Pull my finger". The child pulls grandpa's finger and he farts.  The joke is that the small child is meant to believe that pulling the finger caused grandpa to fart.  Joke dates back to when we all believed that grandpa was a good guy and not immediately think of a pedophile.